# How to organize data for a multivariate probit model?

Tags: r

I've conducted a psychometric test on some subjects, and I'm trying to create a multivariate probit model.

The test was conducted as follows:

To subject 1 was given a certain stimulous under 11 different conditions, 10 times for each condition. Answers (`correct=1`, `uncorrect=0`) were registered.
So for subject 1, I have the following results' table:

```
# Subj 1
      correct
cnt    1  0

  1    0 10
  2    0 10
  3    1  9
  4    5  5
  5    7  3
  6   10  0
  7   10  0
  8   10  0
  9    9  1
  10  10  0
  11  10  0
```

This means that Subj1 answered uncorrectly 10 times under condition 1 and 2, and answered 10 times correctly under condition 10 and 11. For the other conditions, the response was increasing from condition 3 to condition 9.
I hope I was clear.

I usually analyze the data using the following code:

```
prob.glm <- glm(resp.mat1 ~ cnt, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

Here `resp.mat1` is the responses' table, while `cnt` is the contrast `c(1,11)`. So I'm able to draw the sigmoid curve using the `predict()` function. The graph, for the subject-1 is the following.

[image]

Now suppose I've conducted the same test on 20 subjects. I have now 20 tables, organized like the first one.

What I want to do is to compare subgroups, for example: `male vs. female`; `young vs. older` and so on. But I want to keep the inter-individual variability, so simply "adding" the 20 tables will be wrong.

How can I organize the data in order to use the `glm()` function?

I want to be able to write a command like:

```
prob.glm <- glm(resp.matTOT ~ cnt + sex, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

And then graphing the curve for `sex=M`, and `sex=F`.

I tried using the `rbind()` function, to create a unique table, then adding columns for `Subj (1 to 20)`, `Sex`, `Age`. But it looks me a bad solution, so any alternative solutions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the wrong function for the job. Check the first example of `glmer` in package `lme4`; it comes quite close to what you want. `herd` should be replaced by the subject number, but make sure that you do something like

```
mydata$subject = as.factor(mydata$subject)
```

when you have numerical subject numbers.

```
# Stolen from lme4
library(lattice)
library(
xyplot(incidence/size ~ period|herd, cbpp, type=c('g','p','l'),
       layout=c(3,5), index.cond = function(x,y)max(y))
(gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
              data = cbpp, family = binomial))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a multivariate probit command in the `mlogit` library of all things.  You can see an example of the data structure required here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/multinomial-probit-for-varying-choice-set